# magnetic CSS popup

Tags: css, popover

Below is code that i have in my shopify shop that is causing problems especially in google chrome. page popups wont show correctly.  only appear as 30% opaque page overs. a link to a page with such a problem is here [shopify shop example](https://www.japandizness.net/collections/frontpage/products/new-japan-secret-honey-disney-2015-snow-white-dress-version-4) Thanks so much for any help on this!  Jeff :)

```css
/* Magnific Popup CSS */
.mfp-bg {top: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;z-index: 1042;overflow: hidden;position: fixed;background: #0b0b0b;opacity: 0.8;filter: alpha(opacity=80); }
.mfp-wrap {top: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;z-index: 1043;position: fixed;outline: none !important;-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }
.mfp-container {text-align: center;position: absolute;width: 100%;height: 100%;left: 0;top: 0;padding: 0 8px;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing: border-box; }
.mfp-container:before {content: '';display: inline-block;height: 100%;vertical-align: middle; }
.mfp-align-top .mfp-container:before {display: none; }
.mfp-content {position: relative;display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;margin: 0 auto;text-align: left;z-index: 1045; }
.mfp-inline-holder .mfp-content, .mfp-ajax-holder .mfp-content {width: 100%;cursor: auto; }
.mfp-ajax-cur {cursor: progress; }
.mfp-zoom-out-cur, .mfp-zoom-out-cur .mfp-image-holder .mfp-close {cursor:pointer; }
.mfp-zoom {cursor: pointer;cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;cursor: -moz-zoom-in;cursor: zoom-in; }
.mfp-auto-cursor .mfp-content {cursor: auto; }
.mfp-close, .mfp-arrow, .mfp-preloader, .mfp-counter {-webkit-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;user-select: none; }
.mfp-loading.mfp-figure {display: none; }
.mfp-hide {display: none !important; }
.mfp-preloader {color: #cccccc;position: absolute;top: 50%;width: auto;text-align: center;margin-top: -0.8em;left: 8px;right: 8px;z-index: 1044; }
.mfp-preloader a {color: #cccccc; }
.mfp-preloader a:hover {color: white; }
.mfp-s-ready .mfp-preloader {display: none; }
.mfp-s-error .mfp-content {display: none; }
button.mfp-close, button.mfp-arrow {overflow: visible;cursor: pointer;background: transparent;border: 0;-webkit-appearance: none;display: block;outline: none;padding: 0;z-index: 1046;-webkit-box-shadow: none;box-shadow: none; }
button::-moz-focus-inner {padding: 0;border: 0; }
.mfp-close {width: 44px;height: 44px;line-height: 44px;position: absolute;right: 0;top: 0;text-decoration: none;text-align: center;opacity: 0.65;filter:alpha(opacity=65);padding: 0 0 18px 10px;color: white;font-style: normal;font-size: 28px;font-family: Arial, Baskerville, monospace; }
.mfp-close:hover, .mfp-close:focus {opacity: 1;filter: alpha(opacity=100); }
.mfp-close:active {top: 1px; }
.mfp-close-btn-in .mfp-close {color: #333333;}
.mfp-image-holder .mfp-close, .mfp-iframe-holder .mfp-close {color: white;right: -6px;text-align: right;padding-right: 6px;width: 100%; }
.mfp-counter {position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;color: #cccccc;font-size: 12px;line-height: 18px; }
.mfp-arrow {position: absolute;opacity: 0.65;filter: alpha(opacity=65);margin: 0;top: 50%;margin-top: -55px;padding: 0;width: 90px;height: 110px;-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
.mfp-arrow:active {margin-top: -54px; }
.mfp-arrow:hover, .mfp-arrow:focus {opacity: 1;filter: alpha(opacity=100); }
.mfp-arrow:before, .mfp-arrow:after, .mfp-arrow .mfp-b, .mfp-arrow .mfp-a {content: '';display: block;width: 0;height: 0;position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;margin-top: 35px;margin-left: 35px;border: medium solid transparent; }
.mfp-arrow:after, .mfp-arrow .mfp-a {border-top-width: 13px;border-bottom-width: 13px;top: 8px; }
.mfp-arrow:before, .mfp-arrow .mfp-b {border-top-width: 21px;border-bottom-width: 21px;opacity: 0.7; }
.mfp-arrow-left {left: 0; }
.mfp-arrow-left:after, .mfp-arrow-left .mfp-a {border-right: 17px solid white;margin-left: 31px; }
.mfp-arrow-left:before, .mfp-arrow-left .mfp-b {margin-left: 25px;border-right: 27px solid #3f3f3f; }
.mfp-arrow-right {right: 0; }
.mfp-arrow-right:after, .mfp-arrow-right .mfp-a {border-left: 17px solid white;margin-left: 39px; }
.mfp-arrow-right:before, .mfp-arrow-right .mfp-b {border-left: 27px solid #3f3f3f; }
.mfp-iframe-holder {padding-top: 40px;padding-bottom: 40px; }
.mfp-iframe-holder .mfp-content {line-height: 0;width: 100%;max-width: 900px; }
.mfp-iframe-holder .mfp-close {top: -40px; }
.mfp-iframe-scaler {width: 100%;height: 0;overflow: hidden;padding-top: 56.25%; }
.mfp-iframe-scaler iframe {position: absolute;display: block;top: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);background: black; }

/* Main image in popup */
img.mfp-img {width: auto;max-width: 100%;height: auto;display: block;line-height: 0;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding: 40px 0 40px;margin: 0 auto; }
/* The shadow behind the image */
.mfp-figure {line-height: 0; }
.mfp-figure:after {content: '';position: absolute;left: 0;top: 40px;bottom: 40px;display: block;right: 0;width: auto;height: auto;z-index: -1;box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);background: #444444; }
.mfp-figure small {color: #bdbdbd;display: block;font-size: 12px;line-height: 14px; }
.mfp-figure figure {margin: 0; }
.mfp-bottom-bar {margin-top: -36px;position: absolute;top: 100%;left: 0;width: 100%;cursor: auto; }
.mfp-title {text-align: left;line-height: 18px;color: #f3f3f3;word-wrap: break-word;padding-right: 36px; }
.mfp-image-holder .mfp-content {max-width: 100%; }
.mfp-gallery .mfp-image-holder .mfp-figure {cursor: pointer; }

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) and (orientation: landscape), screen and (max-height: 300px) {
/**
* Remove all paddings around the image on small screen
*/
.mfp-img-mobile .mfp-image-holder {padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0; }
.mfp-img-mobile img.mfp-img {padding: 0; }
.mfp-img-mobile .mfp-figure:after {top: 0;bottom: 0; }
.mfp-img-mobile .mfp-figure small {display: inline;margin-left: 5px; }
.mfp-img-mobile .mfp-bottom-bar {background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);bottom: 0;margin: 0;top: auto;padding: 3px 5px;position: fixed;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box; }
.mfp-img-mobile .mfp-bottom-bar:empty {padding: 0; }
.mfp-img-mobile .mfp-counter {right: 5px;top: 3px; }
.mfp-img-mobile .mfp-close {top: 0;right: 0;width: 35px;height: 35px;line-height: 35px;background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);position: fixed;text-align: center;padding: 0; } 
}

@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
.mfp-arrow {-webkit-transform: scale(0.75);transform: scale(0.75); }
.mfp-arrow-left {-webkit-transform-origin: 0;transform-origin: 0; }
.mfp-arrow-right {-webkit-transform-origin: 100%;transform-origin: 100%; }
.mfp-container {padding-left: 6px;padding-right: 6px; } 
}

.mfp-ie7 .mfp-img {padding: 0; }
.mfp-ie7 .mfp-bottom-bar {width: 600px;left: 50%;margin-left: -300px;margin-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 5px; }
.mfp-ie7 .mfp-container {padding: 0; }
.mfp-ie7 .mfp-content {padding-top: 44px; }
.mfp-ie7 .mfp-close {top: 0;right: 0;padding-top: 0; }
```

Comment: You mean the background of the popup is transparent? It's the class `.mfp-bg` with an opacity of 0.8

Comment: if you are on google chrome, viewing the site link for my shopify store,and you click on any of the smaller images--they should open up to a larger image of them, but all i get is the opacity you described, and no image...

Comment: I solved this my reverting all changes back to previous state code.